# Изменение значения у поля в объекте на true или false

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет!
Я новенький в Django Rest Framework.
Есть такая вот модель -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='description', db_index=True, max_length=64)
```

Я хочу добавить в эту модель поле `isActual`, в котором значение будет `True` или `False`

Её значение должно становиться `False`, если пост создан больше месяца. Соответственно, опираться эта логика будет на поле `created`. Не знаю как это реализовать. На сколько это возможно?

Comment: а вообще напишите подробнее, что ходите сделать, ибо много вариантов решений

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю management command, который будет искать среди актуальных
    постов те, что с старше месяца и делать их не актуальными. Запускать
    ее через cron. [О management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

Если это нужно для фильтрации то можно просто фильтровать по дате. А если нужна именно такая реализация то можно для этой цели использовать Celery